# How to deploy PdfSharp to a webhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdfsharp

I have everything working fine on my localhost. I included the lib directory in the project and did a web deploy. nothing is happening and no errors. all the console has for the Pdf webapi get call is a 200ok, and "no properties" inside it. IS there a mapping issue when you upload ?

Comment: It'll work if you do it right. ;-) You don't give us much information. Do you use the WPF build of PDFsharp? Do you have Full Trust on the server? Did you try an application pool running as "System"?

Comment: ok, not sure what you needed. yes I have full trust on server,Yes it is WPF, just read it is better to use GDI for .net? looking into application pool

Comment: I am running IIS Express on my laptop. is this what I need to look into?  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools

Comment: Maybe there are logs on the webhost with additional information. Using an application pool with identity "Local System" (or a similar name) is an easy test to rule out problems caused by lack of privileges. GDI+ version may not work on some webservers (you can still try it if nothing else helps).